# setting up mod_proxy - plesk, apache, .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, proxy

I want to set up mod_proxy to work so that my blog is running under a subdirectory of my site rather than subdomain so i get the seo backlink benefit.

What im looking to do is get my tumblr blog which is running at blog.mysite.com (which is in turn mapped from myblog.tumblr.com) will be running on mysite.com/blog

How can i set up mod_proxy to do this, is it just something that i can setup from inside of my .htacess file ?

Ive got my site hosted on an apache server, using plesk as a controll panel.

I contacted my webhost and they told me mod_rewrite could acheve it, they gave me this but said they wont provide me further support regarding mod_rewrite as its somthing they dont support

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk/blog$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/standard
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.tumblr.com$1   [R]
</IfModule>
```

ideally id like to use the mod_proxy method as it recomended from an seo point of view from this article http://www.seomoz.org/blog/what-is-a-reverse-proxy-and-how-can-it-help-my-seo

Comment: I think you might want something like this: http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/06/tumblr-in-a-subdirectory

Comment: thanks, i can see what the .htacess is doing, but whats the purpose of the php in that tutorial ? - im not to experienced in these things

Comment: The PHP is rewriting the site so that the urls that need to be rewritten to work properly, work. Tumblr urls work a specific way and when you move the "pages" into a new domain and a new folder structure all that needs to be altered.

Comment: great thanks, just had a thought though, when google indexs the directory will it be able to see all the posts even though when you look at the site in an ftp client theres nothing there apart from a php file and an htaccess file. - Also is this method you posted the same as using mod_proxy ?

Comment: Yes, the server you put that code on will be functioning as an HTTP  Proxy, it will accept HTTP requests and pass them through to your tumblr instance, which will reply with content, your proxy will rewrite that content, and pass that rewritten content to the original requestors. It's not mod_proxy, but it's functionally similar. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Web_proxy